# UISplitViewController and UINavigationController doesn't work properly with multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying (for experiment) to work with multiple storyboards.
The first storyboard (starts at startup) contains only one view controller that executes some code and download json data from a website.

[image: first storyboard]

When finish the download task, the view controller (of first storyboard) set the entry Point of Second storyboard as root view controller after instantiating it.

```
UIStoryboard *mainSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UITabBarController *rootTabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[mainSB instantiateInitialViewController];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        ...

        self.view.window.rootViewController = rootTabBarController;
```

This Second story board contains a tabbar controller with a split view controller inside it:

[image: second storyboard]

All works but there is a strange behaviour of navbar controller inside the splitview controller. Its back button works if pressed but doesn't display properly because there is only the "back" text without the left arrow.

[image: ![the problem with navigation bar]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lPaS.png)

**Only after few minutes and some transitions between master and detail view the back button display properly with the left arrow.**

[image: navigation bar ok after some transitions]

(All works correctly if I use only the Second storyboard from the startup)

I Know that in this case I can use only one storyboard but I want to know if is not correct to work in this way with multiple storyboards or if it's a bug.

Comment: Do you know that it works if you have all the controllers in one storyboard? BTW, Apple says that a split view controller should only be the root view controller of the window, not embedded in a tab bar controller.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, if I have all the controller in the same storyboard and perform the specific segue it all works. [StoryBoard](http://i57.tinypic.com/2psk1vp.png)

However, with the TabBar controller and a UISplitView inside it I haven't any problems.

Comment: I tried to remove the UISplitViewController from the second storyboard and leave only the UINavigationController. 
Everything works, so the problem is the UISplitViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new Xcode 7 Beta and iOS 9 all perfectly work.

Whit the same configuration of files the chevron of navigation controller display properly.
I don't know why, Apple in this WWDC has released the storyboard reference, but I think that was a bug of UISplitViewController.